# how i can insert my POST variable value without including comma into my database

Tags: php

I want to insert my php POST variable value without including comma into my database but the value which is coming into database is only numeric one while I am not selecting 1 the function which I am using is as follows kindly provide me the resolution:

```
$loanreq=number_format($_POST['loanreq']);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear....

Comment: rehne do app koi baat nai

Comment: insert direct  `$_POST['loanreq']`  without `number_format` function.

Comment: NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER, NEVER dump variables directly from $_POST into a database without sanitising them:  [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: pleass read this answer it's about how to the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear,

If you want a numeric digit with no commas in it. you can use a simple

```
str_replace( ',', '', $_POST['loanreq'] );
```

Comment: else you can also use  $loanreq= preg_match("/^[0-9,]+$/", $_POST['loanreq']);